# How to plot a single node using tidygraph objects in R?

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I was wondering if it is possible to plot a tidygraph object with a single node? For example, if I create some data and a tidygraph object with 2 nodes, that would look like this:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(graph)
nodes <- data.frame(name = c('var1', 'var2'), value = c(3, 10))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1),
                    to = c(2))

tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)

ggraph(tg, "partition") +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = name)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void()
```

[image: example of 2 nodes]

However, I was wondering if I could plot a tidygraph object that contains just 1 node. For example, if my data had no edge data associated with it, like so:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c('var1'), value = c(3))
tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes)
```

When I try to plot the above, I get the error:

> Error in layout[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Which makes sense because there is no edge data. I, naively, tried to set the edge data to something like:

```
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1),
                    to = c(1))
```

But this throws back an error as well.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve what Im trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a two-row node data frame with the same row repeated twice, the same for the edges data frame. Create the plot object and remove the second row of its data component.

```r
library(tidygraph)
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

nodes <- data.frame(name = c('var1'), value = c(3, 3))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1),
                    to = c(1, 1))

tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)

p <- ggraph(tg, "partition") +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = name)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void()

#Remove second node
p$data <- p$data[-2, ]

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>